# Dashboard Website interacting with a local database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot with a local database (enmap) and I'm making a dashboard website for it to configure prefix and etc but is there a possible way to connect the discord bot's local database with the website?

Comment: You'd have to create an API and create get/post requests. You may also have to utilize websockets.